# Failed to resolve:com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, loopj

I have downloaded jar file of Loopj library and placed it in libs folder. have tried many changes but getting same error. Can anyone please help me to solve this.

build.gradle :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pratik.receivedsms"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies
 {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'

}
```

Comment: Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8
Show in File  Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: Edit your question with whole error log from message tab in Android Studio.!!

Comment: I am getting error which i have mentioned in my heading "Failed to resolve:com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8"  apart from that there is nothing in error log

Comment: I have added  compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8' in my gradle and it works fine though. Clean and Rebuild your project..!!

Comment: solved Problem... Actually my offline mode was enabled that's why i was getting error. Thanks for giving your valuable time. :-)

Comment: Hey Hi yesterday i had sent you text on fb regarding to my spinners query. can you help me on that?

Comment: i think may be we are not friends that's why you didn't get. i have sent you friend request also

Comment: Ohk ..Will look into it..!!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is opening gradle terminal from android studio and executing the following command:

```
    gradlew installarchives
```

- It should also work without downloading the jar file.
- Another note is that I am using version 1.4.5.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Downgrading to 1.4.4 helped to me.